# CodeIgniter login across all pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-scope

I'm am very new to CI the MVC model.

I have a simple page which is made of up 3 views. Header, Content and Footer. The content will be unique across the site but header and footer will be the same, no matter what page.

In my header I have a *login* form. So there will be a *login* form across the whole site. since it appears on every page which has diff models:

**how will or where will I write the script for logging in a user as I don't fancy writing a login script on every model the header is used on...**

**Maybe another example:**

If that's not clear, I try another example. Suppose I have a site. In that I load a view which is a footer in all my pages. and the footer contains a form. Now when I post data using that form, where should that data it go?

Show it go to a dedicated PHP file which handles all the posts from that form, or should it go to the current page' controller?

I hope I was clear. Again I Just started using CI and MVC a day ago. It would be nice if you could guide me.

Comment: So what exactly are you using? CodeIgniter or MVC? Because one does not implement the other, FYI.

Comment: @tereško Well, after some days, I found out that i needed hmvc to support module/widgets/partial-view etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i post data using that form, where should that data it go?

You shouldn't write the logic on every page (controller). What you should do is creating a distinct controller (like `Accounts`) for managing user logging.

The login form should post the data to `accounts/login` URL. but to get back to the previous page, we should store current URL in session as `referer`.

To do that, just store `uri_string();` in the session on each page you need.

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
    'referer' => $this->uri->uri_string()
));
```

If you don't need to redirect the user to the previous page, ignore it.

The example below indicates how to achieve the goal:

```
class Accounts extends CI_Controller {

    public function login()
    {
        $config = array(
            // Write your validation rules here
        );

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

        // Check whether form is submitted
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $data['login_errors'] = validation_errors();
                // Store validation errors in session
                // to display on every page needed
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            } else {

                // Login process
                // Set user detail in session

                // Redirect to previous page after login
                if ($referer = $this->session->userdata('referer')) {
                    $this->session->unset_userdata('referer');
                } else {
                    $referer='';
                }

                redirect(base_url().$referer);  
            }

        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        // Destroy the session
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, this is what i was looking for. thanks! Also i had a look into hmvc, that seems perty cool to as it allows you to have modules/widgets/partial view on ur site

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a model with the global function
2. Put the function in the config autoload.php under "models"
3. You can call this model from from anywhere without loading it