# Condensing a controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller like so :

```
public function index() {

        $data['content'] = 'homepage/login';
        $this -> load -> view('templates/no_jsTemplate', $data);
    }
```

Where index() is the login page ( first page any one will ever see)

Now that index page has a form that sends its post data to :

```
public function login_user() {
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run('c_homepage/login_user') == FALSE) {
            $this -> index();
        } else {
            $this -> load -> model('m_homepage');
            $this -> m_homepapge -> login_user();
        }

    }
```

is it possible to condense this? I feel like having two controller functions per page is excessive no?

I tried this :

```
public function index() {
        if (!$this -> input -> post('login_user')) { // check if submit is clicked, if not then just load the data array and show the view
            $data['content'] = 'homepage/login'; 
            $this -> load -> view('templates/no_jsTemplate', $data);
        } else { // if it is clicked load the library and then do the validation and then load the model if validation passes and then do the login_user business calculation 
            $this -> load -> library('form_validation');

            if ($this -> form_validation -> run('c_homepage/login_user') == FALSE) {
                $this -> index();
            } else {
                $this -> load -> model('m_homepage');
                $this -> m_homepapge -> login_user();
            }
        }
    }
```

but when doing this, this keeps me in a infinite loop of sorts. I have built other applications where I would have a function to load the view, then a function for the controller to send the data to the model. I just want to learn other **Better** ways of doing things. My grade is reflected on this project. My main is goal is to be as **DRY** as possible. I want to try and write less code for more bang. Hopefully this isn't asking of to much.

Comment: If you're looking for best practices, follow these topics to keep your code DRY as possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909126/common-function-across-whole-site/17919417#17919417 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101283/codeigniter-authentication-protocol/18101614#18101614

Comment: @HashemQolami Yes I know how to do what you have answered. My question is though is it possible to have a single controller function take care of the view loading, and the data transmission to the model. I can't seem to get past this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it works, some tweaking may be required, Change your form submit `URL` to `index` function :

**EDITED**

```
public function index() {
    if($this->input->post(null)){
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
        if ($this -> form_validation -> run('c_homepage/login_user') == FALSE) {
            //$this -> index();
            redirect('controller/index', 'refresh');
        } else {
            $this -> load -> model('m_homepage');
            $this -> m_homepapge -> login_user();
            redirect('controller/method', 'refresh');   //ADDED
        }
    }else{
        $data['content'] = 'homepage/login';
        $this -> load -> view('templates/no_jsTemplate', $data);    
    }

}
```

`post(null)` returns all the content, Just for checking if the post array has content or not.

Comment: I'm still stuck in that loop I was having before. why post(null)?

Answer (score 0):

In the following lines, I'm going to indicate the logic, you might want to consider to keep your code **DRY**.

Please **avoid** copying and pasting these lines, you should manipulate it to get it to work on your project. Also read the comments inside carefully.

```
public function index()
{
    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
        // Load validation library
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');

        // Set your validation rules by using $config array
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            // Store the validation error messages
            $data['error'] = validation_errors();
        } else {
            // Do the login process
            $this->load->model('m_homepage');
            $this->m_homepapge->login_user();

            // After user is logged in, do you need to say Welcome to him/her?
            // You might want to fetch user's name from database, so:
            // $data['success'] = "Hello $name, You're logged in." 
            // 
            // If you need to show the `Successfully` message to user at once
            // Store the message in flashdata:
            // $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'message');
            // 
            // Do you want to redirect user to somewhere else?
            // redirect('route', 'refresh');
        }
    } else {
        // This method is called directly and/or without any login POST data.
        // Do you need to do somethin special in this case? put your logic here.
    }

    // Always send a view to the user,
    // If user doesn't send the POST data, it shows the login form,
    // Or if user made a mistake during filling the login form,
    //      you can show the `error` to him/her and also show the form inputs.
    // Or if the user is logged in successfully,
    //      You can show the `success` message to him/her,
    //      Or redirect him/her to another route as mentioned before.
    $data['content'] = 'homepage/login'; 
    $this->load->view('templates/no_jsTemplate', $data);
}
```

---

### Note:

If you stored your validation rules in config file `application/config/form_validation.php`, you do **NOT** need to use `set_rules()` method to set the rules *(as i did)*.  **BUT**, SInce the `Controller/Method` is changed, you should change the `Rule Group` name to yours. in this case it would be `c_homepage/index`:

```
$config = array(
    'c_homepage/index' => array(
        array(
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'passconf',
                'label' => 'PasswordConfirmation',
                'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required'
        )
    )
);
```

> When a rule group is named identically to a controller class/function
> it will be used automatically when the run() function is invoked from
> that class/function.

*- [CI User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)*.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your validation rules to the `config/form_validation.php` file.  If your site requires the use of alot of forms, it might be best to autoload the form validation library.

class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index();

```
public function method()
{

      //If you set the config file to match
      //the controller and method name,
      //you won't need to add it as a param.
      if(!$this->form_validation->run())
      {
          return $this->index();
          //or if your using ajax, you would just send back a status
          //and handle errors on frontend
          return $this->output->set_status_header(401);//un-authorized
      }

      //we got this far so validation must have passed :)
}
```

}

-

```
$config = array(
    'controller/method'  =>  array(
        array('field'=>'name', 'label'=>'Name', 'rules'=>'required|xss_clean')),
);
```